# Subsets of distinct prime factors

Tags: number-theory

Define $\omega(n)$ as the set of distinct prime factors of $n$, and $\mathcal{P}(\omega(n))$ as the powerset of $\omega(n)$.

*eg* $\mathcal{P}(\omega(30))=\{\emptyset,\{2\},\{3\},\{5\},\{2,3\},\{2,5\},\{3,5\},\{2,3,5\}\}$

then define $f(n)$ as the sum of the products of each subset, *eg*

$f(30)=1+2+3+5+6+10+15+30$

Also, as @ajotatxe noted below, $f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)^2d$, and as noted by @DanielFischer $f(n)=\sigma_1(\operatorname{rad} n)$ where $\operatorname{rad} n := \prod\limits_{p \mid n} p$.

Clearly $f(n)<\sigma_1(n)$, where $\sigma_1(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$. Also, clearly $f(n)/(n+1)=1$ when $n$ is prime.

Is it true then, that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{f(k)}{k+1}\sim n$?

Plot of $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{f(k)}{k+1}\right)-n,\ 1\leq n \leq 10^6$:

[image]

Comment: Must $n$ be squarefree ?

Comment: Technically, the product of elements of $\varnothing$ is the empty product which by convention is $1$, so you should either add it to $f$ or explicitly exclude it.

Comment: The empty product is $1$, so you should either add $1$ to your $f(30)$, or say "the products of _the nonempty_ subsets".

Comment: So $f(n) = \sigma_1(\operatorname{rad} n)$ or $f(n) = \sigma_1(\operatorname{rad} n) - 1$. Wouldn't make a difference for whether $\sum_{k\leqslant n} f(k)/k \sim n$ or not.

Comment: But for squarefree $n$, we now have equality : $f(n)=\sigma(n)$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$.

Comment: @Peter no, not as far as I am aware

Comment: $f(n)$ is the sum of the square-free divisors of $n$, that is, $f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)^2d$.

Comment: @DanielFischer what is $\sigma_1(\operatorname{rad} n)$?

Comment: It's the sum of divisors of the radical of $n$. The radical of $n$ is $\operatorname{rad} n := \prod\limits_{p \mid n} p$. More algebraically, it's the generator of the ideal of nilpotents in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$.

Comment: Now what about the equality ? And is $n$ an arbitary number ?

Comment: @Peter yes, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Peter can the sum not "cancel itself out"? Clearly $f(2^k)/2^k$ tends to zero quickly.

Comment: I just noticed that the values are summed. Sorry. But my comment that $f(n)=\sigma(n)$ for squarefree $n$ remains true, but does not help much.

Comment: ? l=10^6;t=0;for(k=1,l,t=t+f(k)/(k+1));print(t/l*1.0)    0.9999923907775124178935792495 ?

Comment: Numerical calculation strongly indicates that the given asymptotic is true.

Comment: @Peter interestingly also, denoting $n$th primorial $\#(n)$ and $n$th prime $p_n$, it appears that $\dfrac{f(\#(n))}{\#(n)}\sim c +\log p_n$ for some $c\approx \gamma$.

Comment: @martin Does $\#(n)$ denote $\prod_{p\leqslant n} p$ or $\prod_{k = 1}^n p_k$? In any case, [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems) is relevant for the behaviour of $\dfrac{f(\#(n))}{\#(n)}$.

Comment: The first leads to $\#(4) = \prod_{p\leqslant 4} p = 2\cdot 3 = 6$. Seems you're using the second then. For the connection to Mertens' theorem, note that $\dfrac{f(m)}{m} = \prod\limits_{p\mid m} \dfrac{p+1}{p}$ for squarefree $m$, and write $1 + p^{-1} = \dfrac{1-p^{-2}}{1-p^{-1}}$. The product of numerators gives you approximately $1/\zeta(2)$, and the product of denominators gives you something $\sim e^{\gamma}\log p_n$ by Mertens.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah, that's nice! :)